# Classless object in shorthand notation

Tags: javascript

So, I dived head first in Marijn Haverbeke's [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/index.html) and swam directly to the [Electronic Life](http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html) chapter.

There we observe the spontaneous generation of an object :

```
 {"#": Wall,"o": BouncingCritter}
```

Wall and BouncingCritter are defined elsewere :

```
function Wall() {}  


function BouncingCritter() {
  this.direction = randomElement(directionNames);
  this.name = word();
};

BouncingCritter.prototype.act = function(view) {
  if (view.look(this.direction) != " ")
    this.direction = view.find(" ") || "s";
  return {type: "move", direction: this.direction};
};

BouncingCritter.prototype.toString=function(){
    return this.name +"\t"+ this.direction;
}
```

---> I don't get what sorcery is happening there.
Well, I see we're creating an object on the fly, and since it's going to be used only once, no need to define a class. OK.
I understand that hitherto this anonymous object has two properties, which are themselves classes, that will be instantiated several times down the road. I'm starting to flutter but I'll get along. One of those (Wall) is quite empty, which will later prove useful as "nothing" is somewhat better than 'undefined'. Fine.

What I don't get is the use of string constants "#" and "o" on the left hand side of the colon. Could someone please expand on this ?

Heartly thanking,

Answer (score 2):

> What I don't get is the use of string constants "#" and "o" on the left hand side of the colon. Could someone please expand on this ?

The property has to be called *something*. Those are just rather unhelpful names which tell you nothing about what the property actually holds.

… until you look at the context. From the link you provided:

> The “#” characters in this plan represent walls and rocks, and the “o” characters represent critters.

It's using `#` as the name for the wall property because that is the symbol used to render it in the UI. Ditto "o"/citter.

(That still isn't a great name though: It tightly couples the internal name to the presentation of it, which would start to fall apart if the UI was later changed to use (for example) pretty graphics instead of ASCII art)

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario it's more like a dictionnary. It just use to say that the character # or o represent respectivly the class Wall and BouncingCritter.

Edit (after reading your book as fast as i could): When he instanciate the `World(map, legend)`, legend is the dictionnary. Later in the code he creates the grid and for every characters from the string representation of the world, he instanciates the correct class according to the legend dictionnary he gave `var element = new legend[ch]();`.

Answer (score 0):

OK folks, thanks for your answers. I dug a bit further and came across a very clear and concise (nifty, indeed) explanation as to the ways of the object literal notation : [Nifty Javascript - Objects](http://www.webmechs.com/javascript-tutorials/nifty-javascript-oop.php).

What confused me most at first in

```
{"#": Wall,"o": BouncingCritter}
```

are the quotes surrounding properties names, and the fact that "#" would otherwise be an illegal character for a property name.

To wrap my head around this, I had to write it down, and I share below, for what it's worth.

The "legend" is anonymous classless object defined, when we construct the World,
by the block  {"#": Wall,"o": BouncingCritter}

Says Marjin :

```
A legend is an object that tells us what each character
in the map means. It contains a constructor for every 
character—except for the space character, which always 
refers to null, the value we’ll use to represent empty 
space.
```

In the World constructor, we populate the grid.space array according to what we
read from the 'map' (which is instantiated by the array 'plan').
The character read from the map (either 'o' or '#') serves as the key in the
hashtable (a.k.a "object") 'legend'. The corresponding value is a class (either 
'Wall' or 'BouncingCritter') which is then instanciated. The resulting object is
finally stored in the grid.space array.

Note that the original literal notation {"#": Wall,"o": BouncingCritter} for 
creation and the subsequent employ of square brackets in the function
'elementFromChar'

```
var element = new legend[ch]();
```

allows for the use of the
otherwise illegal character '#' as the name of the property.

Here be rant :

Needless to say, I'm not very happy with all this. I guess it's the kind of stunt that gives javascript a bad reputation sometimes. All in all, I'm starting to consider that the title of the book, "Eloquent Javascript", may be a little overstated or even plain misleading. 
Granted, it is an impressive demonstration of object-fu maestria, but neither the code nor the text are specially clear. I had a very hard time stitching the code patches together and getting the project to work and I feel that the object breakdown used to model the problem is overly complicated. But heck, I'm learning, so my opinion is completely unauthorized ;-)

end-of-rant